# Hiding a SINGLE File (Apahe)

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, file, hide

I have a HTML file that is full of IP addresses from a PHP script that logs all IP's of vistiots. The only thing is that I don't want people to be able to go to 
https:// mydomain.us/ips.html to see all of the IP's logged. What are my options to hide this **ONE** file.

I read all of these things with a code you put in your .htaccess, but none of them worked!

All I need is a way to hide this HTML file!

Sorry if this a bad question also, I'm really new to all of this :P

PHP Script: 
(Used to write to the HTML File)
http://pastebin.com/jKDHeArb

Final Output (ips.html)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvQde.jpg

Comment: can you do with PHP?  I have a solution for you if you can add a single line of php.

Comment: Yeah! I can do that!

Comment: I added my PHP script above btw!

Comment: And I added the HTML  page that is produced!

Comment: I suggest you include the relevant part of your code and desired/final output in your question with "code" formatting instead of using hyperlinks to other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you put this page in a folder, and protect it with a password. There are many examples here or on the Internet.
But like you do not really want to block the page, but just to hide, You can do this by adding a code at the end of link. With this root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^c=pass$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ips\.html$ - [NC,F,L]
```

After it's possible to visit the page only with the following https link:

```
https:// mydomain.us/ips.html?c=pass
```

You can do the same in the php code.

Comment: When I put that in .htaccess, I could still get there normally! What do you mean by: You can do the same in the php code?

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to either an .htaccess or your Vhost

`<Files ~ "ips.html">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>`

Comment: Umm, I added that to .htaccess and restarted apache, and I can still acess it from domain.com/ips.html

Comment: I can still get to ips.html :(

Comment: where are you writing that? if you are using an htaccess you may have to enable AllowOverride `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Yes, I am using htacess, I just added "AllowOverride All" but I can still access ips.html

Comment: you have to change `AllowOverride All` in global apache config file or your vhost, then restart apache
You can also test doing a test.txt file and disable the access with the code I gave to you, just change ips.html to test.txt

Comment: Oh, my gosh, I just got a 505 error! I changed AllowOverride None to Allow Override All

Comment: `<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>`